# duplicate peripherals appears on scanning using core bluetooth ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have used following

```
scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])
```

It means that duplicate value should get filtered out but it is not getting filtered out and still duplication is occuring what should I do to resolve. Thank you in advance

Comment: allow duplicates = false is the default.  Have you tried specifying nil for `options` ?  What peripheral are you using?  Is it possible that it is sending multiple advertisements or randomising its MAC?

Comment: Yes i have tried by specifying nil to options it gives same result of duplication

Comment: Which delegate method is showing duplicates?  Have you tried the LightBlue app from the app store? Does it see duplicates?  What is your peripheral?

Comment: My peripheral is hardware device and I have one question that scanning second time should show non duplicate peripherals only or shows all devices again with duplication?

Comment: If you stop scanning and start scanning again your delegate methods will be called for all discovered devices.

Comment: I want that once my hardware detected in scanning 1st time then when I will scan 2nd time same hardware device name should not appear in list.What should i do to resolve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62879/discussion-between-paulw11-and-jalak-patel).

Comment: the options parameter is a dictionary. The proper syntax for a literal dictionary is `@[key : value, anotherkey : othervalue]`

Comment: Um, this was asked in a swift context, Sorry, I had missed that. My comment on literal dictionary syntax was for Obj-C.